# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal. Depending on the set value of the context variable the modal will show one of three html groups. Its three modals in one.

The modal populates various html values through an json object:

```
var object = [
      {
        id: 34,
        week: '9/15/20',
        suggestednumber: 6,
        number: null
      },
      {
        id: 674,
        week: '10/13/20',
        suggestednumber: 70,
        number: null
      },
      {
        id: 54,
        week: '11/17/20',
        suggestednumber: 34,
        number: null
      }
    ];
```

Two buttons and a form will populate within the active context for each json object in the array. The form will be pre populated with the suggestednumber value.

```
/* function that populates the buttons and form fields of the selected modal
    takes the css id of the row its populating.
    */

    function populate(cssid){

      /* script for forcasted deplitions tested for loop */
      for( i  = 0; i < object.length; i++){
        $(cssid).append("<div  class=\"col-xs-12\">\n" +
          `      <p class=\"text-left text-uppercase text-muted\">wk of ${object[i].week}</p>\n` +
          "    </div>\n" +
          "    <div class=\"col-xs-4 m-0 p-0\">\n" +
          `      <button onclick=\"cbibuttonclick(${object[i].id})\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-block m-0 p-0\">` +
          `<span id=\"${object[i].id}\" class=\"text-uppercase text-primary cbi\">cbi</span></button>\n` +
          "    </div>\n" +
          "    <div class=\"col-xs-4 m-0 p-0\">\n" +
          `      <button onclick=\"custombuttonclick(${object[i].id})\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-block m-0 p-0\"><span id=\"${object[i].id}\" class=\"text-uppercase text-muted custom\">custom</span></button>\n` +
          "    </div>\n" +
          "    <div class=\"col-xs-4\">\n" +
          "      <form class=\"form-inline\">\n" +
          "        <input type=\"number\"\n" +
          `               onclick=\"formclick(${object[i].id})\"\n` +
          `               onchange=\"update(${object[i].id})\"\n` +               
          "               class=\"form-control finput\"\n" +
          `               id=\"${object[i].id}\">\n` +
          "      </form>\n" +
          "    </div>");
        console.log('this is the iterator for the form creation');
        console.log(i);
        document.getElementsByClassName('finput')[i].value = object[i].suggestednumber;

      }
```

}

Im having an issue with the last line of the above function:

`document.getElementsByClassName('finput')[i].value = object[i].suggestednumber;`

when it runs I get the following error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at populate (file:///Users/christopher.jakob/Documents/softwareprojects/slalom/constellationBrands/modalsublime.html:91:60)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users/christopher.jakob/Documents/softwareprojects/slalom/constellationBrands/modalsublime.html:40:9)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js:2:29453)
    at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js:2:29755) undefined
k.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
t @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
B @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at populate (modalsublime.html:91)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (modalsublime.html:40)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

`document.getElementsByClassName('finput')[i].value = object[i].suggestednumber;`

now whats interesting is when I remove the `[i]` next to the `('finput`) from the above code: 
my code doesn't break, however no buttons show up on the screen.

Is it clear to anyone what the problem may be?

for giggles I put the form value update in its own for loop to be executed after all html code is added by jquery. But the error still persisted

```
// for loop to populate form inputs as it seems trying to do so in one for loop make the thing unhappy 

      for(i =0; i< object.length; i++){
        x = document.getElementsByClassName('finput')[i].value = object[i].suggestednumber;
      }
```

When I console log the find element class jquery call I get this

```
here is the result of attempting to find the form class
modalsublime.html:92 
HTMLCollection []
length: 0
__proto__: HTMLCollection
item: ƒ item()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "item"
__proto__: ƒ ()
apply: ƒ apply()
arguments: (...)
bind: ƒ bind()
call: ƒ call()
caller: (...)
constructor: ƒ Function()
length: 0
name: ""
toString: ƒ toString()
Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()
get arguments: ƒ ()
set arguments: ƒ ()
get caller: ƒ ()
set caller: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
[[FunctionLocation]]: <unknown>
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
No properties
length: (...)
namedItem: ƒ namedItem()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "namedItem"
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
No properties
constructor: ƒ HTMLCollection()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLCollection"
get length: ƒ length()
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Sounds like `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't returning anything because it can't find the anything that matches your class.

Comment: @MattiPrice The jQuery code should be adding an element with a class of "finput"...

Comment: You're attempting to access an array index `i` that doesn't exist, meaning there aren't at least `i` elements in the array.

Comment: @MattiPrice is correct. The form with the class is first added by jquery then the find class code is executed. This is for each loop.

Comment: @Madbreaks but I am trying to access it after its creation

Comment: @yourracistgrandpa You might need to make a jsfiddle of the issue, cause I just tried to mock it up and it worked. I can't seem to be able to get that error to show up. Are teh buttons actually appearing on your page?

Comment: @MattiPrice they are yes. I'm going to try one thing and if that doesn't work I'll do a js fittle

Comment: Could be a timing-issue. Have you console.logged  `document.getElementsByClassName('finput')`?

Comment: @AndreNuechter I have not, trying it now.

Comment: @AndreNuechter just added my results to my question body text

Comment: It says it has a length of zero, so no elements have been added at that point.

Comment: @AndreNuechter kkkkkkkkk Damn it. shouldn't it work. Ugh I wanna go back to developing in Angular =( I don't understand why it isn't being populated!

Comment: eh to hell with it. Im just going to go to sleep

Comment: I suspect the target of `$(cssid).append(...)` here is not `document` but the modal...